# JS. Owl-carousel. Как отследить что дальше нет слайдов?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Некоторая моя логика завязана на

```
function callback(event) {
    if (event.relatedTarget['_drag']['direction'] === "left") 
    {
        curPage++;
    }
    else 
    {
        curPage--;
    }
}
```

на `callback'e` висит `onDragged: callback` при инициализации.

Листаем влево - срабатывает `event` налево и делает свои штуки в методе.
Иногда слайдов попросту может не быть (скажем только 2 слайда) и мы не сможем листнуть влево(нам просто нечего будет показать). Сам `owl` это блокирует, если нечего больше открыть, но `event` выше по прежнему срабатывает и в результате у меня неправильно выполняются блоки кода.

Это как то можно отслеживать и блокировать выполнение метода?

Comment: попробуй не на `onDragged`, а на `translated` или `changed` - может это прокатит

Answer (score 0):

```
function callback(event) {
    if(!event.nextElementSibling || !event.previousElementSibling){
        return
    }
    //если видимых слайдов больше то тогда вышеуказонное решение не сработает нужно будет проверять по index-у текушего event.target 
    if (event.relatedTarget['_drag']['direction'] === "left") 
    {
        curPage++;
    }
    else 
    {
        curPage--;
    }
}
```